# How to draw onto a view canvas without upscaling artifacts when the view parent has a scale factor?

Tags: android, zooming, android-canvas, ondraw

When drawing onto a canvas in a `View`'s `onDraw` method you don't know about any scale factor of its parent. This leads to all views and their drawings being up/down scaled whereby one can explore "pixelized" drawings.

Example: So let's say we've got a child view with a custom drawing

```
class MyView extends View {
    @Override
    public onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       // Draw something fancy here that looks ugly when scaled up
    }
}
```

And we add this this view into a parent view:

```
MyView view = new MyView(this);
parent.addChild(view);
parent.setScaleX(10);
parent.setScaleY(10);
```

The canvas drawing in the subview will thus being upscaled by factor 10. This is due to `onDraw()` providing a canvas to draw to that does not reflect this scale factor. That said the canvas always keeps the same dimensions regardless of its final destination. Thus child views do not have the chance to provide higher resolution drawings when their parents are being scaled up. This obviously leads to scaling artifacts.

You can observe the same behavior when you scale a button's parent view:

[image: Button with parent unscaled]
[image: Button with parent scaled (5x)]

Is there any chance to respect all parents transformations when drawing onto child views? Or is this a general limitation when drawing onto canvases in a view hierarchy where view parents can have a scale factor not equal to 1.

In my use case it is not an option to forward the scale change to all children instead of applying it to the parent. This is due to the fact that there some of those children have animations that modify the scale factor. Hence these animations would override any scale change.

Comment: Canvas.getMatrix () ?

Comment: ``Canvas.getMatrix()`` always returns the identity matrix. Additionally the canvas doesn't provide more space when scale factor > 1.

Comment: and what about View.getMatrix ?

Comment: The supplied Canvas where you draw to does not reflect any parent's scaling. So even if we are able to get the matrix, the canvas doesn't reflect it and is also being scaled after you have drawn onto it.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg can you elaborate `Is there any chance to respect all parents transformations when drawing onto child views?` part? If I understood you correctly, you're scaling parent up and then all views are also getting scaled up. That's an expected behavior and thus child does take into account parent scaling.

Comment: Yes, I expect all child views to being scaled up. When those child views contain fancy graphics (e.g. images) they will be scaled up by their parents leading to scaling artifacts. Thus children do not have the chance to provide higher res drawings when their parents have scale factors > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue takes it roots from Composition pattern. Android View Framework (that's not an official name, but you got the idea) also follows this pattern - `ViewGroup` (base class for all layouts) is essentially a `View`. So, when your layout draws itself it just takes content of all children views. Sounds easy.

Since API Level 11 `View` transformation matrix can be modified via `setScaleX`, `setTranslationX`, etc. methods (well, in fact it was possible before API Level 11, but it was a bit tricky). This transformation is then used to transform drawings of **this particular** `View`. Therefore, when you're applying transformation to `ViewGroup`, you're affecting only `ViewGroup` drawing itself, which in return consists of drawing its children.

Moreover, those transformations are affecting only drawing and dispatch of motion events. So, when you're applying `setScale*` you're just modifying the visual representation of the `View`, while logical coordinates and size of the `View` stays the same (`getLeft`, `getTop`, `getRight`, `getBottom`, `getWidth`, `getHeight`).

Now closer to your question. In short - you're doing it wrong. More detailed explanation follows from my previous statements. By affecting transformation of `View` you're not changing it's logical position and size. Therefore child `View` won't detect anything abnormal while drawing - it draws as if there was no scale at all.

What to do then? I would propose three different solutions.

- My favorite solution that I'm using pretty oftenDetach your `View` from layout being scaled and add it on top of it. Then you'll need to scale this `View` manually, taking into account data behind it.
- Override `setScale` method of layout being scaled to propagate it to children. You can create some interface and check if any of the children implements it.
- Vice versa. In your `View` iterate through the all parents until you'll find the root and then calculate scale accordingly. This shouldn't be to much work if your hierarchy is not too deep.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

1.) I can't detach the views to be scaled as they have other views on top of it. Indeed I have a complex view hierarchy.

2.) What is the interfaced supposed to describe?

3.) What is the objective of calculation the root's scale? And subview doesn't receive a larger Canvas it can draw to when any of its parents is scaled up.